# Ошибка AttributeError: __new_member__ в модуле enum.py

Tags: python, python-3.x

Что делать? Не давно появилась эта ошибка. Когда запускаю скрипт вылезает она. Раньше этого не было.

> AttributeError Сообщение = new_member Трассировка стека:
>   C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\enum.py:270 в
>   EnumMeta.**getattr**

Ошибка есть если в скрипте есть

> from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType 
>   import vk_api from